# ADAL Azure AD Authentication user's login cached from different Azure AD session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

Am currently setting up a web app hosted in Azure using Azure Active Directory for authentication, have almost worked all the kinks out but one issues remains. If a user has logged into a different Directory before hitting my sign-in page (in this case it is a University Office 365 login for email), the credential seems cached and Azure attempts to use it to log into my site, is there a way I can force the login screen on every sign-in and avoid re-use of a cached credential?

Project setup has been mainly standard, ASP.NET MVC architecture with default Azure Active Directory authentication settings.

Thanks!

[A screenshot of the MS login page with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGh0A.png)

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the error into your question, instead of just a screenshot?  The specific error at the bottom, that you freehanded a blue circle around regarding `does not exist in...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered the solution as soon as I posted. Implemented a signout and self-redirect to the sign-in method. Code is below:

```
  public void SignIn(bool? signedOut)
    {
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // If the user is currently logged into another directory, log them out then attempt to
            // reauthenticate under this directory
            if (signedOut == null || signedOut == false)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("SignIn", "Account", routeValues: new { signedOut = true }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme) },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

There are two better ways to handle this.  First, use the tenant-specific Azure AD endpoint for your app.  Your `authority` should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<name-of-your-tenant>`.  That will ensure only users from your tenant can sign-in.  But, if a user tries to sign-in with an account from a different tenant (by selecting an existing session or starting a new one), they will receive the error you screenshotted.  No way to prevent that.

If you want to make sure the user enters their username/password every time they sign into your app, you can send the query parameter `prompt=login` in the sign-in request.  But realize that this will break SSO for your users.

Comment: Your second option is more appealing as single sign on isn't that important in this case. Can you describe exactly how to append the query parameter   via the challenge method? I have been through the Owin docs several times and can't seem to work out how? Thanks, Craig