# How to write E2E test for the application backed with adal Login?

Tags: angular, webdriver, protractor, adal

we have an angular application which is having only adal login possible.

Want to ask if it is possible to write the E2E test case using protractor for this where in i can login and then test my actual functionality?

if yes, it would be great how we can achieve this?

below is something i have tried but not working

My test case looks like below

```
it('should display message saying app works', () => {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    page.navigateToLogin();
    page.fillCredentials();
    page.waitForRedirect(100000).then(() => {
      page.navigateTo();
      //// Some Expectations here
    });
  });

below are the supporting methods

  fillCredentials() {
     // browser.findElement(by.id('cred_userid_inputtext')).sendKeys('test@microsoft.onmicrosoft.com');
    // browser.findElement(by.id('cred_password_inputtext')).sendKeys('*******');
//     browser.findElement(by.id('cred_sign_in_button')).click();
    element(by.id('i0116')).sendKeys('test@microsoft.onmicrosoft.com');
    element(by.id('i0118')).sendKeys('********');
    element(by.id('idSIButton9')).click();
  }

  waitForRedirect(timeout: number = browser.getPageTimeout) {
    // Before we tell the browser to wait, assume it has not navigated
    let hasRedirected = false;

    // Passing a function to browser.wait() tells protractor to call that function repeatedly.
    // This function returns the closure variable hasRedirected, which will be set to true once the
    // necessaryUrlFragment has been found in the url
    return browser.wait(() => {
      browser.getCurrentUrl()
        // Check to see if necessaryUrlFragment is in the current url
        .then(url => {
          return (url.indexOf('home') > -1);
        })
        // Update our navigation status
        .then(hasNavigated => {
          hasRedirected = hasNavigated;
        });

      // Return our navigation status every time protractor asks for it - even if navigation is
      if (hasRedirected) {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
        return hasRedirected;
      }
      // not complete
    }, timeout);
  }
```

Edit: Here fill credentials is not working as expected. the `https://login.microsoftonline.com` page takes the username but always logs in with my cached credentials from the browser. instead of using the credentials passed via protractor

Answer (score 0):

If you have a non-angular login page it is sometimes useful to handle it within the before each or beforeAll hooks. That way you can ensure that you page is in the correct state when your tests begin.

Also you should be able to achieve something similar to what you had for your waitForRedirect function using [protractors expectedConditions](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.urlContains)

```
beforeAll(() => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    page.navigateToLogin();
    page.fillCredentials();
    page.waitForRedirect();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
});

it('should display message saying app works', () => {
    //Now your home page should be loaded
    //// Some Expectations here
});

fillCredentials() {
    element(by.id('i0116')).sendKeys('test@microsoft.onmicrosoft.com');
    element(by.id('i0118')).sendKeys('********');
    element(by.id('idSIButton9')).click();
}

waitForRedirect(timeout: number = browser.getPageTimeout) {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    return browser.wait(EC.urlContains('home'), 10000);
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the update and the solution provided. the changes you suggested works fine but the issue is  here fillcredentials() is not working as expected. the `https://login.microsoftonline.com` page takes the username but always logs in with my cached credentials from the browser. instead of using the credentials passed via protractor. also if this works i was thinking to put this login code in protractor.conf.js `OnPrepare` where it will be always loggedin when test case is executed.

Comment: I am not familiar with how Adal works unfortunately so I won't be able to assist you with troubleshooting your cached credentials issue. I did find an article and previous question which may be of assistance however https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241841/adal-azure-ad-authentication-users-login-cached-from-different-azure-ad-session